# In Blackadder Goes Forth, Corporal Punishment, Captain Darling (Counsel for Prosecution) is a defense witness. Is this allowed in a court martial?

Tags: united-kingdom, rules-of-court, military, law-in-fiction, witness

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_tdLCFRaPY&t=152s

Basically, Lieutenant George (accidentally called to be the defense counsel, because Baldrick sent for the wrong person) tries to get Captain Darling, who is the prosecutor against Captain Blackadder, to be a defense witness.

Darling actually does have firsthand accounts of the events in question, he tried to phone Blackadder to tell him his orders from the general were to do something, but Blackadder claimed that there was static on the line.

Granted, I don't know of any reason why Darling would be qualified as a lawyer either.

Comment: "I don't know of any reason why Darling would be qualified as a lawyer either." In courts martial, cases were generally prosecuted and defended by military officers rather than lawyers (at least until very recently and even then, only for more serious offenders - in modern U.S. practice, legally trained JAG corps lawyer-officers now fill this role). From the uniforms in the video, I would assume a WWII or earlier context in the U.K., which would predate lawyer-officer court martial trials there.

Comment: The charge was shooting a carrier pigeon. The pigeon happened to be General Melchett's beloved pet pigeon - Melchett presiding over the court martial and called as witness for the prosecution by Captain Darling.

Comment: "General, did you own a lovely, plump, speckily pigeon called Speckled Jim, which you hand reared from a chick and which was your only childhood friend?"

Comment: It should be pointed out that, although Blackadder Goes Forth does have serious undertones at times (especially the ending), it is a comedy series. So it shouldn't be relied on for historical accuracy.

Comment: @ohwilleke It's set during the First World War. It is effectively a satire of life in the trenches.

Answer (score 0):

> Darling actually does have firsthand accounts of the events in question,

people who have knowledge and relevant testimony are generally allowed in courts and courts-martial.  A prosecutor who was part of the case would generally be recused.

Comment: I would bet that this answer is correct. I'm downvoting anyway because it appears to just be guess and does not cite any law.

Comment: I wouldn't be too confident of these conclusions in the court-martial context, particularly re the recusal of the prosecutor.

Comment: @ohwilleke for the US, I can find no proscription in the UCMJ or Military rules of Evidence of a trial counsel  providing direct evidence, but I would find it highly unlikely that the convening authority would allow the trial counsel to remain at such a position upon finding out they needed to provide direct evidence.